# In $C_{\infty}$ , find all singularities for $\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I know it has pole of order 2 at z = 0 but I'm not sure it has essential singularity at z = $\infty$.

In $C_{\infty}$ , $\pm\infty , \pm i\infty$ are same point. They should give same value if it doesn't have essential singularity at z = $\infty$.

z = $\infty$ , $lim_{w\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{w}(e^{\frac{1}{w}}-1)} = 0$

but z = $i\infty$ , $lim_{w\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{i}{w}(e^{\frac{i}{w}}-1)} = lim_{w\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{i}{w}(\cos{\frac{1}{w}}+i\sin{\frac{1}{w}}-1)}$

I think it isn't analytic at z = $i\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of complex analysis, there is one point at infinity, denoted by $\infty$. The function $f$ has a singularity at $\infty$ if $f\left(\frac1z\right)$ has a singularity at $0$. But\begin{align}f\left(\frac1z\right)&=\frac1{\frac1z\left(e^{\frac1z}-1\right)}\\&=\frac z{e^{\frac1z}-1}\end{align}Note that this is undefined when $z$ has the form $\frac1{2\pi i}$, for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore, if you are talking of *isolated* singularities, then $\infty$ isn't one. Otherwise, it is a limit point of isolated singularities.

Comment: Is it not as same as case of $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ at  z = 0 which has essential singularity at z = 0

Comment: @RoTheory No, since $0$ is an isolated singularity of $\exp\left(\frac1z\right)$.